# Groupby Sum in R or Python

Tags: python, r, dplyr

I have a dataset, df1

```
 Length  Duration
  90     10
  90     3
  90     5
  80     2
  80     2
```

I need to groupby Length and then sum

I am thinking I will have to

```
 library(dplyr)

  df1 %>%
  Group_by(df1$Length) %>%
  Sum(df1$Duration)
```

Desired Output:

```
Length    Sum

90         18      
80         4
```

dput

```
structure(list(Duration = c(10L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L), Length = c(90L, 
90L, 90L, 80L, 80L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: `df1 %>%
  group_by(Length) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(Duration))
`

Comment: No need to use $ to define columns, as you are passing the name of the dataframe at the beginning of the pipe.